# Pythonのプログラムを対話実行中に呼び出せないでしょうか

Tags: python, python3

例えば以下のようなファイルがあるとして

```
# add.py
a = 1
b = 2
c = a + b
```

これをPythonの対話実行中に呼び出して、cの値を確認するようなことはできないでしょうか？
print文でデバッグしなくて済むのでプログラミングがものすごく楽になるのですが...

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 小さなプログラムなら[これ](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit)も良く使って居ます。

Comment: 教えていただいてありがとうございます！これ便利ですねー！

Answer (score 3):

解決しました！

Pyhton -i add.py のようにオプションiをつけて起動することによって、
スクリプト実行後に対話入力モードにシフトすることができました。

Comment: `python -m pdb add.py` のように実行することで、デバッグモードで1行ずつ確認しながら実行もできます。

Comment: おお！ありがとうございます！
デバッグモードも便利ですね。早速使わせていただきました！ご教示ありがとうございます。